# Array of CGColorRef objects

Tags: ios, arrays, core-graphics

I'm trying to create a gradient texture in SpriteKit.

To do that, I have to use a `CAGradientLayer` and render an image. My problem is with setting the colors.

From Apple's Documentation:

> An array of `CGColorRef` objects defining the color of each gradient stop. Animatable.

So in code, I tried this:

```
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor].CGColor, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];
```

This doesn't work, because `CGColorRef` is not an object type and cannot be sent to type `id`. My error is:

> Incompatible pointer types sending `CGColorRef` (aka `struct CGColor *`) to parameter of type `id`

How can I create an array of `CGColorRef`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an array literal and cast to `(id)`:

```
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
```

[image]

Comment: This looks amazing! +1 for the screencap!

Comment: @DDPWNAGE you are welcome :) the mac screenshots always look awesome with the shadow borders ;)

Comment: To achieve this result a quick snap of code below 
Write below code in viewDidLoad
CAGradientLayer *layer = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    NSArray *colors = @[(id)UIColor.redColor.CGColor, (id)UIColor.greenColor.CGColor, (id)UIColor.blueColor.CGColor];
    layer.colors = colors;
    [layer setFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
Will get the result like [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/1abzra7h37991h7/Screenshot%202019-04-11%2008.14.05.png?dl=0